# Protecting admin page without database

Tags: php

Lets say I have a page called protected.php . Is it safe to do something like this:

```
<?php 
if( $_GET["id"]=="a_very_hard_number")){
     continue script;
} else{
    echo  dont_hack_me; 
}
```

So if I want to access the page myself, I will visit the page using the URL:    `www.mysite.com/protected.php?id=a_very_hard_number`. I just want to know if this is safe. Since the ID is only known to me, is there any other way to bypass this?

Comment: Unless or otherwise others know your ID, it is safe

Comment: Define safe. Will it be impossible to crack? No, nothing is. the ID might be picked up from someone sniffing your traffic or somewhere else. It's hard to answer and really depends how far you are willing to go.

Comment: I tink it wl b gud to change the id periodically..

Comment: Additionaly you could make requests per SSL - sniffing will be not possible...

Comment: Yea..gud idea.. Thanks

Comment: Isn't better idea to do it even without php? using .htaccess & .htpasswd (just saying...)

Comment: There is a better yet easy way. Check this : http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/password-protection/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the PHP Header Authentication instead of this.

Checkout its documentation as below.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php
Checkout Example #2 from there.

Hope it will solve your queries.